# Error message displaying prior to submit button click

Tags: php, validation, html-email

Maybe some one can help me with this issue.  Created a form and i'm using PHP to validate email input. The Error variable is being displayed when page loads up and not when submit button is clicked. how can i resolve this issue.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==="POST"){





$emailErr = "";
$email = "";

 if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
 $emailErr = "Email is required";
 } else {
 $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
 // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
 if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
   $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
 }
  }
 }

?>                           <!---[1]-->
<form id="myform" action="formval2.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkinfo()">

 <label for="name">First Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="fname"><span id="errorname"></span>
 <br/>

<label for="FirstName">Lastt Name</label> 
 <input type="text" name="LastName" id="lname"><span id="errorlname"></span>
<br/>

 <label for="password">Password</label>
 <input type="password" name="Password" id="pw"><span id="errorpw"></span>
 <br/>

 <label for="email">Email</label>
 <input type="email" name="Email" id="email"><span id="erroremail"><?php print "$emailErr";?  ></span>
 <br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="val()"/>

</form>
```

Comment: Use `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")` as in `==` instead of single `=`

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison seems to use a single =. In PHP, comparisons are double ==. So change your comparison:

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
```

This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This would work better

```
if(isset($_POST["email"])) {

    $emailErr = "";
    $email = "";



    if (filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $emailErr = "Email is not valid";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    }
}else {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
}
```

Changed so it only looks if `$_POST["email"]` is set, because if it is we know the user have posted the form and we don't need to check that twice. Also your regex is invalid and PHP already has a function that can validate email addresses.

### **Edit**

`<input type="email" name="Email" id="email">` should be `<input type="email" name="email" id="email">` so the name matches in the HTML and PHP.

Comment: The email is showing up in post array but the error message is missing, any suggestions? ... i plugged in your code and i was receiving the same non error when left empty

Comment: Same issue it is still pooping in when page loads ..... i have even removed the Server request and noting.... I wonder if i have to user PHP_self,,,Unless you have an other suggestions

Comment: `<input type="email" name="Email" id="email">` should be `<input type="email" name="email" id="email">` with no capital letters in the name.

Comment: Heres what i got with Server Request it wont show the variable error when i try to submit, but when i remove the Request it will display error when when pay loads, so im assuming that i need to modify the request. and i updated the name on the input thanks for the tip completely missed it